# How to ignore errors when executing SELECT from Snowflake STAGE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading a set of JSON files from a Snowflake stage into a table by running INSERT..SELECT against the stage location. I am doing it this way instead of COPY INTO because I need to capture input file names, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(FILE_NAME, JSON_VALUE)
SELECT METADATA$FILENAME,$1 FROM @MYSTAGE(FILE_FORMAT => MYJSON)
```

The challenge is I need to be able to ignore possible source file formatting errors, and this method does not support the ON_ERROR clause. I use regular COPY_INTO then I can specify ON_ERROR but cannot capture source file names. Is there a way for me to achieve both - capture source file names and ignore errors when loading files into Snowflake tables?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transformation with the `COPY` so I would use that instead:

```
COPY INTO MYTABLE(FILE_NAME, JSON_VALUE)
 FROM ( SELECT METADATA$FILENAME,$1 FROM @MYSTAGE(FILE_FORMAT => MYJSON) )
```

Comment: Thanks - this way I can use the ON_ERROR option. Tested and it worked!